# Firefox ip address randomly changing

Tags: firefox, proxy

I have been using ubuntu for a couple of years now and I have never seen something as strange as this happen before. I went on [http://www.speedtest.net/](http://www.speedtest.net) to test my internet speed and noticed in the bottom left, where it displays your ip address, it was showing an address registered in the Dominican Republic. I am certainly not there, in fact I am in Europe. When I refreshed the page, it showed a different address which still was definitely not mine. I then visited http://whatsmyip.net/ and the same thing happened. Every time I refreshed the page, a new ip address was shown. What is even more strange is this only happens in firefox. I am not running any VPN software or browsing through a proxy (I have checked my system settings and firefox's settings and proxies are disabled). This does not happen in QupZilla or on the text browser Lynx. It only happens on firefox running on ubuntu.

I would appreciate any suggestions as to why this is happening and any possible solutions.

NOTE: As nice as it is to have a random IP address generated for me for every page I visit, it leads to very slow browsing and up to 500ms ping. The anonymity is simply not worth it and http://www.whatsmyip.org/ **did**
manage to get my real IP.

Comment: You have any tor-related or proxy-related plugins or installed packages?

Comment: I'd also wager that it's some add-on or another. Please provide a list or screenshot of all your installed Firefox add-ons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the tor-button plugin for Firefox?

https://www.torproject.org/docs/torbutton/index.html.en

Or the tor version of firefox...

https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en

*The Tor software protects you by bouncing your communications around a distributed network of relays run by volunteers all around the world: it prevents somebody watching your Internet connection from learning what sites you visit, it prevents the sites you visit from learning your physical location, and it lets you access sites which are blocked.*

That would appear to be what's happening to your connection.

Comment: It wasn't tor but it was another extension I had installed. Thanks for the suggestion.